# Node.js sticky-session, what if mobile IP has been changed?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ip, handshake, sticky-session

We know **sticky-session uses hash of IP address** to make each client connect to same cluster(or process). And instead, I use sticky-cluster which has same principle, but much better.

Then... **what if IP changes in mobile?**
We also know every mobile device move, its IP could be changed.
If it happens, the handshake protocol will be broken.

In case of me, Because I have to use socket.io to make messenger app, I must solve this.

***Actually,*** I sent email to sticky-cluster developer, Denis Zhbankov,
and he said 
it is a drawback of sticky-session, but master should decide which worker receive connection without actually read data (headers, cookies..)..... unfortunately there was no solution... so I came here.

But I tried to find solution. I hope it will help you for hint.

```
function serverCreate () {
   var hash = require('string-hash');
  return require('net')
            .createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function (connection) {
        var index = hash(connection.remoteAddress || '') % CONCURRENCY;
        workers.entrust(index, connection);
   });
}
```

This is code sample of sticky-cluster. As you see it uses hash of ip, get idx, and pass connection to workers[ idx ]. (Balancing)
At here, I thought there would be some unique identifier, which can replace ip, in connection (argument). So I unwraped the connection(Socket) object.
But there was nothing to replace ip...
It was stupid! :D

If you have any ideas to solve this problem, please answer anything..;)

**Short:** How to make a client to connect same cluster even client IP changes in mobile when using sticky-session.